# How can I check for each record in the json file if a value exists?

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have a.json file with these values.

**file.json**

```
[{
        "Championship": "CALCIO\nALBANIA Super League\n2023/2024",
        "Day": "Giornata 29",
        "Matches": [
            {
                "Day": "Giornata 29",
                "Matches": {
                    "Home": "Egnatia",
                    "Away": "Kukesi",
                    "Times": "29.03. 15:00",
                    "Logo Home": "https://static.flashscore.com/res/image/data/CzPXaD96-byNKiB8E.png",
                    "Logo Away": "https://static.flashscore.com/res/image/data/vJ05JXkC-xYAyYwqs.png",
                    "Championship": "CALCIO\nALBANIA Super League\n2023/2024",
                    "Difference": ""
                }
            },
            {
                "Day": "Giornata 29",
                "Matches": {
                    "Home": "Tirana",
                    "Away": "Teuta",
                    "Times": "29.03. 19:00",
                    "Logo Home": "https://static.flashscore.com/res/image/data/6J7hyple-4n770DLk.png",
                    "Logo Away": "https://static.flashscore.com/res/image/data/d6TJntiT-lriBSRvS.png",
                    "Championship": "CALCIO\nALBANIA Super League\n2023/2024",
                    "Difference": "4:00:00"
                }
            },
            {
                "Day": "Giornata 29",
                "Matches": {
                    "Home": "Vllaznia",
                    "Away": "Erzeni",
                    "Times": "29.03. 19:00",
                    "Logo Home": "https://static.flashscore.com/res/image/data/Q78gNKWH-G4kYWTwf.png",
                    "Logo Away": "https://static.flashscore.com/res/image/data/xKwIrSS0-vqMNBv4d.png",
                    "Championship": "CALCIO\nALBANIA Super League\n2023/2024",
                    "Difference": "inferiore"
                }
            },
            {
                "Day": "Giornata 29",
                "Matches": {
                    "Home": "Laci",
                    "Away": "Partizani",
                    "Times": "30.03. 15:00",
                    "Logo Home": "https://static.flashscore.com/res/image/data/2ogjpF86-YRn3qYc4.png",
                    "Logo Away": "https://static.flashscore.com/res/image/data/KMUe5pUH-4praOw3K.png",
                    "Championship": "CALCIO\nALBANIA Super League\n2023/2024",
                    "Difference": "20:00:00"
                }
            },
            {
                "Day": "Giornata 29",
                "Matches": {
                    "Home": "Din. Tirana",
                    "Away": "Skenderbeu",
                    "Times": "30.03. 18:00",
                    "Logo Home": "https://static.flashscore.com/res/image/data/hAEvEniC-bBJMyX2M.png",
                    "Logo Away": "https://static.flashscore.com/res/image/data/6uRmtaCN-Cn9OLcXB.png",
                    "Championship": "CALCIO\nALBANIA Super League\n2023/2024",
                    "Difference": "3:00:00"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Championship": "CALCIO\nALBANIA Super League\n2023/2024",
        "Day": "Giornata 27",
        "Matches": [
            {
                "Day": "Giornata 27",
                "Matches": {
                    "Home": "Din. Tirana",
                    "Away": "Teuta",
                    "Times": "03.04. 18:00",
                    "Logo Home": "https://static.flashscore.com/res/image/data/hAEvEniC-bBJMyX2M.png",
                    "Logo Away": "https://static.flashscore.com/res/image/data/d6TJntiT-lriBSRvS.png",
                    "Championship": "CALCIO\nALBANIA Super League\n2023/2024",
                    "Difference": ""
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Championship": "CALCIO\nALBANIA Super League\n2023/2024",
        "Day": "Giornata 30",
        "Matches": [
            {
                "Day": "Giornata 30",
                "Matches": {
                    "Home": "Kukesi",
                    "Away": "Din. Tirana",
                    "Times": "07.04. 15:00",
                    "Logo Home": "https://static.flashscore.com/res/image/data/vJ05JXkC-xYAyYwqs.png",
                    "Logo Away": "https://static.flashscore.com/res/image/data/hAEvEniC-bBJMyX2M.png",
                    "Championship": "CALCIO\nALBANIA Super League\n2023/2024",
                    "Difference": ""
                }
            },
            {
                "Day": "Giornata 30",
                "Matches": {
                    "Home": "Partizani",
                    "Away": "Vllaznia",
                    "Times": "07.04. 18:00",
                    "Logo Home": "https://static.flashscore.com/res/image/data/KMUe5pUH-4praOw3K.png",
                    "Logo Away": "https://static.flashscore.com/res/image/data/Q78gNKWH-G4kYWTwf.png",
                    "Championship": "CALCIO\nALBANIA Super League\n2023/2024",
                    "Difference": "3:00:00"
                }
            },
            {
                "Day": "Giornata 30",
                "Matches": {
                    "Home": "Teuta",
                    "Away": "Laci",
                    "Times": "07.04. 18:00",
                    "Logo Home": "https://static.flashscore.com/res/image/data/d6TJntiT-lriBSRvS.png",
                    "Logo Away": "https://static.flashscore.com/res/image/data/2ogjpF86-YRn3qYc4.png",
                    "Championship": "CALCIO\nALBANIA Super League\n2023/2024",
                    "Difference": "inferiore"
                }
            },
            {
                "Day": "Giornata 30",
                "Matches": {
                    "Home": "Erzeni",
                    "Away": "Egnatia",
                    "Times": "08.04. 15:00",
                    "Logo Home": "https://static.flashscore.com/res/image/data/xKwIrSS0-vqMNBv4d.png",
                    "Logo Away": "https://static.flashscore.com/res/image/data/CzPXaD96-byNKiB8E.png",
                    "Championship": "CALCIO\nALBANIA Super League\n2023/2024",
                    "Difference": "21:00:00"
                }
            },
            {
                "Day": "Giornata 30",
                "Matches": {
                    "Home": "Skenderbeu",
                    "Away": "Tirana",
                    "Times": "08.04. 18:00",
                    "Logo Home": "https://static.flashscore.com/res/image/data/6uRmtaCN-Cn9OLcXB.png",
                    "Logo Away": "https://static.flashscore.com/res/image/data/6J7hyple-4n770DLk.png",
                    "Championship": "CALCIO\nALBANIA Super League\n2023/2024",
                    "Difference": "3:00:00"
                }
            }
        ]
    }]
```

I would like to check for each primary record, within the ['Matches']['Difference'] key, whether it has a "inferiore" value, preferably in the simplest way possible, perhaps with the all() or any() function, how can I do? any advice on this?

**I expect an output like this:**

CALCIO\nALBANIA Super League\n2023/2024 - False

etc....

When False it means that at least one "inferiore" exists within the primary record.

Comment: I've tried everything, checking if the word == 'inferiore' is present in the specific key but the desired result doesn't come out